# When exactly does Preprocessing of c++ Header file occur

Tags: c++, header, c-preprocessor

So I have a header file that creates a struct that looks something like this..

"CreateStruct.h"

```
#define CREATE_STRUCT(NAME, VAR) \
        struct NAME {\
            DECLARE_VAR(VAR)\
        };\

#define DECLARE_VAR\
        //....
```

"main.cpp"

```
#include "CreateStruct.h"
//....
```

This compiles fine and creates the struct correctly..

The only thing I'm curious about is WHEN exactly this processing happens..

Does it happen when the main.cpp is finished compiling?

Or does it happen immediately when the compiler sees the line `#include "CreateStruct.h"`?

Comment: The prefix "pre" in the name "preprocessor" should give you a hint.

Comment: Oh, and check [this reference of the different compilation phases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases).

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessing is the first step, it happens before the compilation. All macros are extended, and header files are replaced by their content, after this happen, the program is compiled.

You can see the preprocessor output by using the option -E

```
gcc -E main.cpp
```

Comment: If you want to get technical, macros are expanded during the fourth phase of translation, so beyond being pretty much the first visible step, some stuff happens before that.

Comment: @chris If they are expanded during the fourth phase, how come they are displayed with gcc -E?

Comment: @Mansuro Phases 1 through 6 are all "preprocessing" because phases 7 through 9 are compilation and linking. The `-E` option gives you the output after phase 4.